# Check the state of the web application C#

Tags: c#

I am working with 2 applications say A and B. Data goes from A to B and B processes the data and gives the output, this output is displayed in application A to the user. User cannot see the working process of application B. 
 My query is, if application B goes down during the process.How should i check it? 
Application B is WebApplication.

Is there any way to check the state of the web page if it's navigate from one page to other or if the web page goes down?

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of a heartbeat signal that goes from your web application to your "A" application. In A you periodically receive that signal and reset a counter that runs up to a given timeout limit in case B does not send a signal any more, in which case you know the B is down. Accordingly, you may need a similar mechanism between your frontend in-page application (most probably Javascript) and your web application. For this case I usually use the SignalR framework. It allows for event-triggered notification from the server to the browser in a very comfortable way with different fallback technologies for older browsers/environments.